# Comparing pandas Series for equality when they contain nan?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, nan, equality-operator

My application needs to compare Series instances that sometimes contain nans. That causes ordinary comparison using `==` to fail, since `nan != nan`:

```
import numpy as np
from pandas import Series
s1 = Series([1,np.nan])
s2 = Series([1,np.nan])

>>> (Series([1, nan]) == Series([1, nan])).all()
False
```

What's the proper way to compare such Series?

Comment: Would you consider changing your accepted answer? ^^

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about this. First check the NaNs are in the same place (using [isnull](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isnull.html)):

```
In [11]: s1.isnull()
Out[11]: 
0    False
1     True
dtype: bool

In [12]: s1.isnull() == s2.isnull()
Out[12]: 
0    True
1    True
dtype: bool
```

Then check the values which aren't NaN are equal (using [notnull](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.notnull.html)):

```
In [13]: s1[s1.notnull()]
Out[13]: 
0    1
dtype: float64

In [14]: s1[s1.notnull()] == s2[s2.notnull()]
Out[14]: 
0    True
dtype: bool
```

In order to be equal we need both to be True:

```
In [15]: (s1.isnull() == s2.isnull()).all() and (s1[s1.notnull()] == s2[s2.notnull()]).all()
Out[15]: True
```

*You could also check name etc. if this wasn't sufficient.*

If you want to *raise* if they are different, use [`assert_series_equal`](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/util/testing.py#L235) from `pandas.util.testing`:

```
In [21]: from pandas.util.testing import assert_series_equal

In [22]: assert_series_equal(s1, s2)
```

Comment: This works, too bad it raises an exception rather than just returning False.

Comment: thanks, this works well. I think it might make sense for Pandas to add a method that abstracts this little snippet to Series.

Comment: I was just thinking the same thing, I was *sure* you didn't have to do this.

Comment: @Sam's answer with **`Series.equals()` should be the accepted answer and has been correct since [0.13.1 (Feb 2014)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.13.1/whatsnew.html#id1)**

Comment: This answer is still correct if you want element wise comparison, rather than a single boolean result.

Answer (score 8):

Currently one should just use `series1.equals(series2)` see [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.equals.html). This also checks if `nan`s are in the same positions.

Answer (score 0):

I came looking here for a similar answer, and think @Sam's answer is the neatest if you just want 1 value back. But I wanted a truth-array back with an element-wise comparison (but null safe).

So finally I ended up with:

```py
import pandas as pd

s1 = pd.Series([1,np.nan, 2, np.nan])
s2 = pd.Series([1,np.nan, np.nan, 2])

(s1 == s2) | ~(s1.isnull() ^ s2.isnull())
```

The result:

```
0     True
1     True
2    False
3    False
dtype: bool
```

Comparing this to `s1 == s2`:

```
0     True
1    False
2    False
3    False
dtype: bool
```

Answer (score -1):

```
In [16]: s1 = Series([1,np.nan])

In [17]: s2 = Series([1,np.nan])

In [18]: (s1.dropna()==s2.dropna()).all()
Out[18]: True
```

Comment: Jeff, your solution ignores the position of the NaNs: `(Series([1, nan]).dropna() == Series([nan, 1]).dropna()).all() #=> True`