# Comparing NaN columns in pandas/numpy

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I want to compare two columns in a dataframe which may contain NaN values.

Based on [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18453442/comparing-pandas-series-for-equality-when-they-contain-nan) I have tried to adapt my code but am struggling with the following:

```
(s1[s1.notnull()] == s2[s2.notnull()]).all()
```

How can I adjust this code so that I do not need to extract s1 and s2 as series from the dataframe but can apply it directly:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

mydata = [{'SystemA': 1.78, 'SystemB':1.78},
          {'SystemA': 2.5, 'SystemB':2.5},
          {'SystemA': np.nan, 'SystemB':np.nan}]

df = pd.DataFrame(mydata)
print(df)

# does not return single True or False
# gives wrong result when e.g. 2.5 is changed to 2.6 in just one column
c =  (df['SystemA'].notnull() == df['SystemB'].notnull()).all()

print('\nc:',c)
```

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you're after here, your code works as expected, what are you trying to test here?

Comment: Unfortunately it returns "True" also if I change the 2.5 in "SystemA" to 2.6.

Comment: @Uwe that's expected behaviour. Do you know what `.notnull()` does?

Comment: Ups, of course. You are right! Mea culpa

Answer (score 11):

The `equals` method ignores nans:

```
>>> df
   SystemA  SystemB
0     1.78     1.78
1     2.50     2.50
2      NaN      NaN
>>> (df["SystemA"] == df["SystemB"]).all()
False
>>> df["SystemA"].equals(df["SystemB"])
True
>>> df.iloc[1,1] = 2.6
>>> df
   SystemA  SystemB
0     1.78     1.78
1     2.50     2.60
2      NaN      NaN
>>> df["SystemA"].equals(df["SystemB"])
False
```

although it also checks for dtype equality, so if you have a Series of integers and a Series of floats, it'll say they're not equal even if you have

```
>>> ((df.SystemA == df.SystemB) | (df.SystemA.isnull() & df.SystemB.isnull())).all()
True
```

This may or may not be a problem for you.

Answer (score -1):

```
mydata = [{'SystemA': 1.78, 'SystemB':1.78},
          {'SystemA': 2.5, 'SystemB':2.5},
          {'SystemA': np.nan, 'SystemB':np.nan}]

df = pd.DataFrame(mydata)
```

This will get you rows where both cols are null:

```
df[pd.isnull(df['SystemA']) & (pd.isnull(df['SystemB']))]

    SystemA     SystemB
 2  NaN     NaN
```

This will get you rows where both cols are notnull:

```
df[(df['SystemA'].notnull()) & (df['SystemB'].notnull())]

SystemA     SystemB
0   1.78    1.78
1   2.50    2.50
```

I'm assuming you something along the lines of one of those?

Comment: Here I get "TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str" for both lines of code

Comment: Oh, sorry I assigned `mydata` to a DataFrame, I'll edit

Comment: I there a way to get a single `True` or `False` back if all comparisons succeed or fail?

Comment: see DSM's answer for your True / False :)

Answer (score -2):

is that what you are looking for:

```
df['SystemA'].dropna() == df['SystemB'].dropna()
```

?

Comment: I think it does since, well, it removes the NaNs from each series and compares the remaining rows. Together with the isnull() comparison from the linked example it should be sufficient I believe (need to think about it).